# AoC Day 24 2017: Electromagnetic Moat

Tags: c#, programming-challenge, design-patterns, recursion

This year's [AoC](http://adventofcode.com) has a puzzle for day 24 that was (supposedly) intended to be solved with recursion.

Here is the description:

> --- Day 24: Electromagnetic Moat ---
>
> The CPU itself is a large, black building surrounded by a bottomless
>   pit. Enormous metal tubes extend outward from the side of the building
>   at regular intervals and descend down into the void. There's no way to
>   cross, but you need to get inside.
>
> No way, of course, other than building a bridge out of the magnetic
>   components strewn about nearby.
>
> Each component has two ports, one on each end. The ports come in all
>   different types, and only matching types can be connected. You take an
>   inventory of the components by their port types (your puzzle input).
>   Each port is identified by the number of pins it uses; more pins mean
>   a stronger connection for your bridge. A 3/7 component, for example,
>   has a type-3 port on one side, and a type-7 port on the other.
>
> Your side of the pit is metallic; a perfect surface to connect a
>   magnetic, zero-pin port. Because of this, the first port you use must
>   be of type 0. It doesn't matter what type of port you end with; your
>   goal is just to make the bridge as strong as possible.
>
> The strength of a bridge is the sum of the port types in each
>   component. For example, if your bridge is made of components 0/3, 3/7,
>   and 7/4, your bridge has a strength of 0+3 + 3+7 + 7+4 = 24.
>
> For example, suppose you had the following components:
>
> ```
> 0/2
> 2/2
> 2/3
> 3/4
> 3/5
> 0/1
> 10/1
> 9/10
> ```
>
> With them, you could make the following valid bridges:
>
> ```
> 0/1
> 0/1--10/1
> 0/1--10/1--9/10
> 0/2
> 0/2--2/3
> 0/2--2/3--3/4
> 0/2--2/3--3/5
> 0/2--2/2
> 0/2--2/2--2/3
> 0/2--2/2--2/3--3/4
> 0/2--2/2--2/3--3/5
> ```
>
> (Note how, as shown by 10/1, order of ports within a component doesn't
>   matter. However, you may only use each port on a component once.)
>
> Of these bridges, the strongest one is 0/1--10/1--9/10; it has a
>   strength of 0+1 + 1+10 + 10+9 = 31.
>
> What is the strength of the strongest bridge you can make with the
>   components you have available?

I've solved it via simple direct recursion:

```
var temp = File.ReadAllLines(@"N:\input.txt").Select(x => (int.Parse(x.Split('/').First()), int.Parse(x.Split('/').Last()))).ToList();
var workChain = new HashSet<(int, int)>();
var map = new Dictionary<(int, int), List<(int, int)>>(temp.Count);
foreach (var entry in temp)
{
    map.Add(entry, nextStack(entry));
}
int maxStr = 0, maxLen = 0, lenStr = 0;
temp.Clear();
temp.AddRange(map.Keys.Where(x => isRoot(x)));
foreach (var root in temp)
{
    workChain.Clear(); nextPiece(root, 0);
}
Console.WriteLine($"{maxStr} {lenStr}");

//helpers
bool isRoot(ValueTuple<int, int> node) { return node.Item1 == 0 || node.Item2 == 0; }

int chainSum(HashSet<(int, int)> curChain) // still faster than LINQ
{
    int sum = 0;
    foreach (var piece in curChain)
    {
        sum = sum + (piece.Item1 + piece.Item2);
    }
    return sum; }

int stackable(ValueTuple<int, int> cur, ValueTuple<int, int> tar, int p)
{
    if (commonPort(cur, tar) == p && cur.Item1 == cur.Item2 && cur.Item1 == p) { return p; }
    if ((cur.Item1 == tar.Item1 || cur.Item1 == tar.Item2) && cur.Item1 != p) { return cur.Item1; }
    if ((cur.Item2 == tar.Item1 || cur.Item2 == tar.Item2) && cur.Item2 != p) { return cur.Item2; }
    return -1;
}

int commonPort(ValueTuple<int, int> current, ValueTuple<int, int> target)
{
    if (current.Item1 == target.Item1 || current.Item1 == target.Item2) { return current.Item1; }
    else if (current.Item2 == target.Item1 || current.Item2 == target.Item2) { return current.Item2; }
    else { return -1; }
}

ValueTuple<int, int> nextPiece(ValueTuple<int, int> selected, int p)
{
    var x = (-1, -1);
    workChain.Add(selected);
    foreach (var piece in map[selected])
    {
        if (!selected.Equals(piece) && stackable(selected, piece, p) != -1 && !isRoot(piece) && !workChain.Contains(piece))
        {
            x = nextPiece(piece, stackable(selected, piece, p));
            if (x.Equals((-1, -1)))
            {
                int str = chainSum(workChain), len = workChain.Count;
                maxStr = str > maxStr ? str : maxStr;
                if (len > maxLen)
                {
                    maxLen = len;
                    lenStr = str;
                }
                else if (len == maxLen && str > lenStr)
                {
                    lenStr = str;
                }
                workChain.Remove(piece);
            }
        }
    }
    return x;
}

List<(int, int)> nextStack(ValueTuple<int, int> selected)
{
    workChain.Clear();
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.Count; i++)
        if (!selected.Equals(temp[i]) && commonPort(selected, temp[i]) != -1 && !isRoot(temp[i]))
            workChain.Add(temp[i]);
    return new List<(int, int)>(workChain);
}
```

I hate it, it is ugly as hell and I feel like there should be something simpler and more elegant **without** explicit/direct recursion. I feel like Visitor or Composite could be a better solution to this, although I heard Python users used iterative generators.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

### Readability

I'll focus this review around this statement:

> *I hate it, it is ugly as hell and I feel like there should be more simpler and elegant ..*

You then suggest some object-oriented (visitor, composite) and functional (generator) patterns as ways to improve readability. I would indeed make the code adhere more to OO principles.

---

#### Separation of Concerns

The first phase of refactoring the functional code is to define the concerns. You have: (1) Input Parsing (2) Calculator (3) Output Rendering. Ensure you split these concerns, by either providing separate classes, but definately separate methods, each focusing on their concern.

---

#### Object-Oriented Design

You have chosen `Dictionary<(int, int), List<(int, int)>>` as your state for the calculator. ValueTuple instances are great replacements for boiler-plate classes that group certain properties together. However, when you need re-occuring behavior, they are not the best choice. Have a look at some convoluted statements:

snippet 1:

> ```
> if (commonPort(cur, tar) == p && cur.Item1 == cur.Item2 && cur.Item1 == p) { return p; }
> if ((cur.Item1 == tar.Item1 || cur.Item1 == tar.Item2) && cur.Item1 != p) { return cur.Item1; }
> if ((cur.Item2 == tar.Item1 || cur.Item2 == tar.Item2) && cur.Item2 != p) { return cur.Item2; }
> return -1;
> ```

snippet 2:

> ```
> if (current.Item1 == target.Item1 || current.Item1 == target.Item2) { return current.Item1; }
> else if (current.Item2 == target.Item1 || current.Item2 == target.Item2) { return current.Item2; }
> else { return -1; }
> ```

These are a direct consequence of not having provided custom classes. The `(int, int)` tuple you are using everywhere represents a `Component` in the puzzle. Let's make a class for it.

```
class Component : IEnumerable<int>
{
    public int Port1 { get; }
    public int Port2 { get; }

    public Component(int port1, int port2) => (Port1, Port2) = (port1, port2);

    // methods ..

    public IEnumerator<int> GetEnumerator()
    { 
        yield return Port1;
        yield return Port2;
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

Getting the common port can then be a method in this class.

```
public int? GetCommonPort(Component other) => this.Intersect(other).FirstOrDefault();
```

You may even decide to make a class `Port` to store some additional information which may be useful for linking components together. Only a disconnected port can get connected to a disconnected port of another component. This information is required to decide which components and which of their ports can connect.

```
class Port
{
    public int PortNumber { get; }
    public bool IsConnected { get; internal set; }

    public Port(int portNumber) => PortNumber = portNumber;
}
```

Another class I could imagine is `Bridge`, as it's a chain of components.

```
class Bridge
{
    Component First { get; private set; }
    Component Last { get; private set; }

    public void Construct(Component next)
    {
        Last.Connect(next);
        Last = next;
    }

    // and so on ..
}
```

This should give you a good idea how to rewrite the algorithm using an object-oriented approach. 
Have a go at it..

Comment: Perhaps we should rename the site from code review to home work review. Nice solution though

Comment: @PPann we have the [tag:homework] for it ;-]